# How can i solve routing issue that works on simulator but not on device for my react native driver app?

Tags: react-native, codeigniter, push-notification, angular2-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an e-hailing, driver and user app. When a new request is made from the user to rider app, the notification comes on the driver mobile phone but its not routing. Though it routes on simulator.
This routing happens seamlessly on my simulator but it doesn’t on the real device when it’s deployed for testing.

Other routes (onpress routes) navigate well, but this one based on a functionality doesn’t.

Please how do i solve this? Anyone experienced this before?

I'm looking at a solution where the routing would happen not only on simulator but also on the main device. i've tried many things no success.